# Which Macbook Pro to buy? MID-2012 or MID-2017?

Tags: laptop

The last known upgradable MBP is mid-2012 release.

**MBP MID-2012**

- *2.9GHz I7-3520M up to 3.6GHz
- *16GB DDR3 1600MHz RAM (Upgrade from 4GB)
- *128GB SSD (Upgrade from HDD)
- *1TB HDD (Replaced CD ROM)
- *HD Graphics 4000
- *13.3" 1280x800 NON-RETINA DISPLAY
- *Supports MacOS Mojave 10.14 (I believe that 10.15 will not support this release anymore as 10.14 drops support on MBP 2011).
- *Costs around **750USD** (Upgrades included).

**MBP MID-2017**

- *2.3GHz I5-7360U up to 3.6GHz
- *8GB LPDDR3 2133MHz RAM
- *128GB SSD
- *Iris Plus Graphics 640
- *13.3" 2560x1600 RETINA DISPLAY
- *Supports MacOS Mojave 10.14 (Probably will support updates in the next 5 years)
- *Costs around **1,220USD**

I am only planning to use it on software/mobile application (Android & iOS)/website development. Do you think newer MBP is worth it? I don't really care about the display that much.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but note that you won't be able to do any upgrades on the 2017 model. Both the RAM and storage are welded onto the mainboard.

Comment: One more factor would be to check whether the 2012 one already supports USB 3. USB 2 file transfers can get boring (but then it may not matter if you really just do dev work on it.)